# 'context:component-scan' not working

Tags: java, xml, spring

while running the application, it is throwing the below error in XML

```
The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'.
```

but i have added `xmlns:context` and schema as well. i tried with spring 4.0 too.
Could anyone please help?

please see the full code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="mypack" />

</beans>
```

Comment: Can you paste your entire `applicationContext.xml` file please?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to post the error?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

Comment: xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd

Comment: http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
">
    <context:component-scan base-package="mypack" />

</beans>

Comment: error below org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 13 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 54; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'

Comment: Can you list the Spring jars in your classpath? Possible version mismatch or missing one?

Comment: i tried with Spring 3.2.7 (NetBeans 8) and also with Spring 4.0. Context libraries are present

Comment: Then you don't actually have the libraries in the classpath.

Comment: is there something like context component scan wont work in latest spring version. i am new to this, sorry if my question does not make sense.

Comment: from where can i download and which should be the version?

Comment: You've been asked to list the Spring jars from your classpath. That would be a good place to start if you would want us to help you further.

Comment: spring-aop,spring-aspects,spring-beans,spring-build-src,spring-context,spring-context-support,spring-core,spring-expression,spring-framework-bom,spring-instrument,spring-instrument-tomcat,spring-jdbc,spring-jms,spring-messaging,spring-orm,spring-oxm,spring-tx,spring-test,spring-web,spring-wbmvc,spring-webmvc-portlet,spring-websocket. Above are the jars listed in my folders. spring version is 4.0.1.

Comment: it worked when i changed the xml file like below                  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" (with respective schema)

Comment: If i add all the XML combination (like c,jee etc) with these, it wont work? Could anyone please explain why this happened like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it worked when i changed the xml file like below:

```xml
<beans xmlns="springframework.org/schema/beans";
    xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    xmlns:aop="springframework.org/schema/aop";
    xmlns:context="springframework.org/schema/context";
    xmlns:flow="springframework.org/schema/webflow-config";
    xmlns:lang="springframework.org/schema/lang";
    xmlns:p="springframework.org/schema/p";
    xmlns:util="springframework.org/schema/util";
```

(with respective schema)